# Segmentation fault (x86 assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .data

message db 'juMping JAck flaSh #1',0x0a
len_s equ $-message

section .text

        global _start
_start:
mov ebp,10
top_loop:
dec ebp
jz out_loop
print:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx, message
        mov ebx, len_s
        int 80h
jmp top_loop
mov ebp,0
mov al, 90
out_loop:
SetIndex:

        cmp al,[ebp]
        jge change
change:
        loadl:  mov al, [message+ebp]
        makeC: sub al,32
        inc ebp
        jmp SetIndex

next:   mov [message + ebp],al

print2: mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,message
        mov edx, len_s
        int 80h

        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 80h
```

when i try to execute this program i get a segmentation fault error
i am trying to print the message 10 times and change all small letters to capital letters.
i dont know where the error can be i am pretty new to x86 assembly code

Comment: This is a great time to learn how to use a debugger, which at least will tell you where the error is.

Comment: Three hints: (1) When will the two instructions following `jmp top_loop` be executed?  (2) When `ebp` contains 0, what does `cmp al, [ebp]` do? (3) For the conditional jump `jge change`, what will be executed next in the two possible conditions?